# Eclipse Generate All getters setters in package

Tags: eclipse, getter-setter

Is there a way to generate all getters and setters in an entire package in eclipse?
Thanks.

Comment: You probably want to add details of what programming language you're using; I'm assuming Java, because you're using Eclipse, but that's by no means the only possibility.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're using Java, you may want to take a look at [Project Lombok](http://projectlombok.org/).

Comment: `Package` is pretty specific to JVM based languages though, yes? (Presumably he's using at least Java or Scala . . .)

Answer (score 0):

Generating getters and setters on everything in an entire package seems like a very bad idea. Not everything should be accessible or modifiable. Good OO design includes knowing when to encapsulate by keeping some things private.

That said, you might already know this. If you're looking to do this for some academic exercise, feel free to disregard.

Comment: You're making assumptions...how do you know this isnt a package of all java beans?

Comment: I made no assumptions, and no conclusions based upon assumptions. I said it seems like a bad idea.