# generic getter method

Tags: java, generics, methods, return

I need help figuring out how to implement a generic getter method.  Here's the code I have so far:

```
public class Pair<X extends Comparable<X>, Y extends Comparable<Y>>
    implements Comparable<Pair<X, Y>>{

    private final X first;
    private final Y second;

    public GENERIC getX() {
        return X;
    }

    public GENERIC getY() {
        return Y;
    }
```

Could someone explain to me how to replace the GENERICs with some sort of `<A extends classA> A` object return type for this class?  I've seen examples of other methods with generic return values but I'm failing to understand how to apply it here.  Thanks!

Comment: please look at the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3851355/a-more-generic-return. It could be useful

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change from

```
public GENERIC getX() {
  return X;
}
```

to

```
public X getX() {
  return first;
}
```

The `extends` is a `type constraint`, required when the typename is first encountered. The nameholder for that type is its name

Comment: oh *facepalm*, I should be returning first and second, I was getting them confused, that was dumb of me. And X and Y would then make sense for object types... Thank you!!

Comment: happens to all of us. glad it helped.

Answer (score 1):

You already have defined `X` and `Y` has your generic types.  You simply need to specify them in your method signatures.  Then return your instance variables as usual.  You'll also need something to initialize your `Pair`, such as a constructor (although setter methods would work too):

```
public Pair(X x, Y y)
{
   first = x;
   second = y;
}

public X getX() {
    return first;
}

public Y getY() {
    return second;
}
```